# Moving from polynomials into radical functions: does algebraic geometry still work?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Say I have a polynomial: $x + y = 0$, but subject to the constraints $x = \sqrt{1-u^2}$, $y = \sqrt{1-w^2}$, $u\in[-1,1],w\in[-1,1]$.  I can re-write my original polynomial as an inequality: $\sqrt{1-u^2} + \sqrt{1-w^2} = 0,  u\in[-1,1],w\in[-1,1]$, but then I've moved from polynomials into radical functions.  Do the tools of algebraic geometry still work?  In particular, can I still assume that the solution to the second formulation of the problem can be found as the union of solutions to a set of semi-algebraic sets?

Comment: Can you just rewrite your constraints as $x^2 + u^2=1$ and $y^2+w^2=1$?, and then only consider solutions with $x$ and $y$ positive?

Comment: I believe so, with the unfortunate caveat that the solution using my computer (for a more complicated but similar example) is not exact with your form, and is much better with my form.  In particular, it leaves it as a RootOf... object (it's Maple) with your form, but in my form it solves it parametrically

Comment: So you're unable to clear radicals and write polynomial constraints?

Comment: Actually I think I solved my own problem.  With an appropriate parameterization, I can get the equations to be polynomials again.  I think I was getting hung up on how it parameterizes.  Thanks for the help, it's a polynomial again.  However, I guess the question still stands: do radical functions admit themselves to a nice theory like algebraic geometry?  Can they always be transformed into polynomial constraints?

Comment: Would the Tarski-Seidenberg theorem help?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm still not quite familiar with that theorem.  As I understand it, though, it relates to reduction of dimension of the variety, while here I'm moving from a polynomial into a radical system of equations, which (as far as I know) do not, in general, form algebraic varieties unless they can be transformed into polynomials...